# Is this system time-invariant?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I have this system:
$$y[k] = (1 + (-1)^k)x[k]$$
I would like to know if it is time-invariant or not. I've done some work and came out with this:
$$y_1[k] = (1 + (-1)^k)x[k - k_0] = y_2[k] = (1 + (-1)^{k-k_0})x[k - k_0]$$
Which simplifies to this:
$$x[k - k_0] = (-1)^{k_0}x[k - k_0]$$
Which means that the system is time-invariant but only when $k_0$ is a multiple of $2$. Does the logic make sense here?

Comment: You, and those who have answered, are working too hard. Suppose $x$ is the unit pulse or discrete impulse and so $x[k]$ is $0$ for all $k\neq 0$ while $x[0]=1$. Then, $y[k]=0$ for all $k$. Delay $x$ by $1$ to get $\hat{x}$ so that it is $\hat{x}[1]$ that has value $1$ now while all other $\hat{x}[k]=0$.  Now, $\hat{y}[k]=0$ for all $k$ except $k=1$ when $\hat{y}[1]$ has value $1$. Clearly, delaying the input by $1$ does not delay the output by $1$; $\hat{y}$ is **not** a delayed version of $y$. Ergo, not a time-invariant system.

Answer (score 2):

> Which means that the system is time-invariant but only when k0 is a multiple of 2.

If the system is only time invariant at certain starting times, then it's not time-invariant; it's time-varying.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is absolutely correct. Since the property is not true for every $k$<sub>0</sub>, the system is not time invariant

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna modify your system just slightly, with a 6 dB attenuation.

$$ y[n] = \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}\,x[n] $$

So it simply selects the $y[n]=x[n]$ for even-valued $n$ and sets $y[n]=0$ for odd-values of $n$.

$$\begin{align}
 y[n] &= \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}\,x[n] \\
\\
  &= \begin{cases} 
x[n] \qquad & n=2m  \\
0  & n=2m+1 \quad \end{cases} \qquad m\in \mathbb{Z} \\
\\
   &= \tfrac{1}{2} \,x[n] + \tfrac{1}{2} e^{j \pi n} \,x[n] \\
\\
\end{align}$$

This is an operation and can, under certain situations, be included among other signal-processing blocks that are LTI and have transfer functions.  This is a **decimator** or **down-sampler** with a sample-rate ratio of $\frac12$.  And has gain (from one sample rate to the lower sample rate) of 1.

Now what this does at the higher sample rate (that of $n$) is that the spectrum of $x[n]$ is scaled by $\frac12$ (or -6 dB) and shifted by half-Nyquist and overlap-added.  But if $x[n]$ is low-pass filtered to be empty in the top octave (or top half of the spectrum), then that overlapping destroys no information and $y[2m]$ contains all of the information that $x[n]$ has.